# get All resources on azure powershell whose Tags start with (or include) a particular String - Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I have almost 20 resources in azure, 4 of them have been given Tags @

```
{"Office1work"="work"}
{"Office2practice"="Practice"}
{"Office3practice"="Practice"}
{"Office4practice"="Practice"}
```

Now I want to get the resources whose Tag names start with the keyword "Office".
I know to get a resource by a TagName,for example "hello",  I simply use the following command,

> get-azureRmResource -TagName "Hello"

How can I use the -Tagname property of get-azurermresource to give me all resources whose tags are starting with the keyword "Office" ?

Or is there any other good method to get all resources whose Tags start with a particular string?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code snippet:

```
$resources = Get-AzureRmResources
$resources.foreach{ if ($PSItem.tags.keys -match '^Office') { $PSItem } }
```

First you get all the resources in the subscription, then you filter out all the resource whose tags do not match the 'Office' "expression".

as @LotPings points out, it would probably make more sense to filter without saving to a temporary variable:

```
$resources = Get-AzureRmResources|Where-Object {$_.tags.keys -match "^Office"}
```

Also, I didnt notice you were asking for a `starts with` filter, so you should use `^Office` as a more strict filter (if you need to).

Comment: Wouldn't `$resources = Get-AzureRmResources|Where-Object {$_.tags.keys -match "^Office"}` be more efficient?

Comment: well, you could use `^Office` as a filter, sure, i, honestly, didnt notice he said `starts with` i thought its `contains`. as for the where filter, yeah, it probably would, but unless you have hundreds of thousands of object it wouldnt really matter (unless you have a reeeeeally crappy pc) @LotPings